# plyr and vue.js: accessing the video duration by a computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plyr

I'm trying to dynamically load content based on the duration of the video I'm showing.  I'm having trouble reading the `duration` property. Does it have something to do with the timing of when plyr appears in the DOM?

Let's say I have a vue template with this line:

```
<div ref="dur"> duration: {{ functionOfDuration }} </div>
<plyr>
  <video id="vidplayer" v-on:timeupdate="updatePosition">
    <source src="videos.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</plyr>
```

Then in the vue component I have:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
  },

  computed: {
    functionOfDuration: setInterval(function () {
      const player = new Plyr('#vidplayer');
      if(player.readyState > 0) {
        return player.duration;
      }
    }, 200),
  },
};
<script>
```

The `setInterval` is meant to recheck periodically so that the property functionOfDuration is eventually set once player.readyState is true.

I get the error `[Vue warn]: Getter is missing for computed property "functionOfDuration".`

---

Note that code that reads the duration later will find the property:

```
  methods: {
    updatePosition(t) {
      const player = new Plyr('#vidplayer');
      this.$refs.dur.innerHTML = player.duration;
    },
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `vue-plyr`, you can access duration by @timeupdate event

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
     <div>Duration: {{ duration }}</div>
        <plyr @timeupdate="videoTimeUpdated" :emit="['timeupdate']" ref="player">
          <video>
              <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
      </plyr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      duration: null,
      player: null
    };
  },
  components: {},
  mounted() {
    this.player = this.$refs.player.player;
  },
  methods: {
    videoTimeUpdated: function(event) {
      this.duration = this.player.currentTime;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You can check my demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/6y7r8zk8ow

Comment: This is the current time of the video in its playback; not the duration, which is the total length of the video.

Comment: thank you, you've solved my problem

this.player?.duration - and you will get duration
https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#options